# Connect a GPS Device (NOT another cellphone) to Firebase and retrieve its location in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, gps, location

Its a pretty general question, but Ive done my research and found nothing about specifically  connecting it to Android. But I have found some GPS Devices that use a SIM Card to connect to the Internet and can send a link to its location using google maps if you send a command to it via SMS.
Ive thought about making a button that sends that SMS and receives that link. But that would make the user get charged Extra fees for sending SMS text message. Is there any other way I can do it? ANy GPS Device you may recommend?

Comment: I'm sure that there is no device which supports anything related to firebase from stock. You can for example use Raspberry Pi, connect some GPS module to it, and write some app for it to send data.

Comment: Hello, thank you for telling me. I will research about it. How has it been working for you??

Comment: It has not been working for me. I didn't try